# Fully isolate digital and analog sections to reduce EMI when driving DC loads with PWM. I2C data corruption

Tags: microcontroller, pcb-design, design, emi-filtering, mixed-signal

I am working on a mixed-domain portable *secret project* based on the venerable ATMEGA2560 that will essentially control 3 DC heaters using MOSFETs, communicate with an external controller via UART and read a series of sensors via I2C.

**Project conditions and requirements:**

1. The whole project will be powered by a single battery.
2. The heaters are embedded onto some external PCBs in the form of serpentine heaters (of around 4 Ohms per heater).
3. Each PCB has a group of I2C addressable temperature sensors mounted on the opposite side of the heaters.
4. Heaters and I2C temp sensors MUST coexist on the same PCB as it is a mandatory requirement from the project I was commissioned to work on.
5. The PCB will work under extreme conditions of temperature and humidity.

Under these conditions, I have faced serious issues with EMI when driving the heaters with a standard PWM signal (~490 Hz) AND reading the sensors at the same time. The I2C signal gets corrupted ~~and the MCU freezes~~* by the induced EMI from the heaters (which are basically acting as big inductors/antennas).

The spikes created by the PWM pulses are the main suspects in the corruption of the signal (obviously). So far I have tried shielding and screening my input wires without any substantial change, however, I am wondering what more *aggressive* actions I should take to tackle my issues.  For instance, I could isolate the controller board from the analog signal paths wherever possible, add PCB board [shields](https://www.mouser.co.uk/new/wurth-elektronik/wurth-shc/) to protect from EMI

Additional actions could involve:

1. To power the board from the battery using a [Traco Power](https://www.tracopower.com/sites/default/files/products/datasheets/tes5wi_datasheet.pdf) 5V 5W DC/DC converter.
2. To feed the PWM signal to the output MOSFETs through optocouplers with transistor output.
3. Using twisted pairs, screened/shielded data cables and single-point grounding as much as possible.
4. To increase the number of layers in the PCB design with big ground pours to reduce interference. Doing this, the I2C bus lines could be buried between two ground planes.
5. To "sprinkle" RC and RL filters throughout the board.
6. Similarly, add ferrite beads *everywhere*

**System blocks**

It could look something like this:

[image: system blocks]

**My concerns are:**

1. The isolation will be broken on the data communication lines namely UART and I2C unless optical coupling is also considered for those (increasing the complexity of the project)
2. Unless I do use the isolated DC/DC converter, feeding the board using a single battery *kind of* defeats the purpose of isolation since there will invariably be a ground return. Isn't it?
3. From the previous diagram, the sections with the pink crosses will "beak" the isolation, unless I use optical coupling, based on [this](https://www.embedded.com/opto-electrical-isolation-of-the-i2c-bus/) resource. Should I go with an optically isolated I2C bus? Speed might be an issue...
4. Would passive filtering like RC and RL circuits plus ferrite beads have a strong effect against EMI?
5. What are the most reasonable ways to minimise EMI?

**EDITS/MORE INFO**

I want to clarify that corruption in the I2C bus is my main issue. I managed to find some pictures I took a couple of weeks ago of the I2C bus being *destroyed* as soon as I turned the heaters on:

with the heaters off:

[image: heaters off]

as soon as I turn the heaters on:

[image: I2C bus corrupted]

Also, my issues are DEFINITELY not related to power delivery. I have used my 20A bench power supply during all of my tests.

Finally, I have confirmed that the MCU does NOT freeze. That was related to an issue with the serial monitor I was using and it's been sorted. The only issue is related to data corruption of the I2C bus.

Comment: Seems you *suspect* EMI as the corruption cause. From your system description, power distribution to various parts could also be a cause (I'm thinking of the problem of common-ground). Star-grounding with battery at the nexus might be considered.

Comment: How about turning off the heaters for the very brief period you need the rum the i2c bus to make the measurements? Also why does the MCU freeze? If it’s simple spinning wait for i2c data that never arrives due to corruption you can always break that loop and try again

Comment: Is there a specific reason the electronics are isolated? Isolation generally won’t help and might be even making the problem worse. I’d also suggest to avoid using I2C sensors as I2C isn’t really good in noisy environments. It was meant for chip to chip comms on a pcb. Use a smd diode or thermistor for temp sensing.  much easier to filter the signal.

Comment: Kartman is correct about avoiding IIC when board-to-board communications is required.  You will want a more robust communication scheme when going off board.

Comment: @glen_geek thank you for your comment. My issues are NOT power-related. Te I2C bus is definitely getting corrupted as soon as I turn on the power supply for the heaters. Star-grounding is a good idea, though. Thanks!

Comment: @Bryan yes! I have considered doing that, however, one goal is to close the loop with a PID algorithm and thus the heaters AND I2C signal will be continuously used at some point. I could do some trickery like saving the value of the temperature sensors and then passing the values to the PID objects and once the computation is complete, turn the heaters on and off before reading the sensors again. My concern is the poor response times this will cause

Comment: @Kartman the blocks diagram I shared does NOT correspond to the system I am having issues with. It is a hypothetical system that would use optical isolation wherever possible. We have also considered using analog sensors, however, one peculiarity of this design is that the temperature sensors are arranged in a matrix [nxm] and thus they are monitored by (x, y) coordinates using only the 2 lines of the I2C bus. Multiplexing analog sensors (which are also slow) will be a big issue for the intended performance

Comment: @Bryan I forgot to correct myself. You are right asking "why does the MCU freeze?" it does not! It turns out that it was my serial monitor the one playing with me. The I2C data is the only thing getting corrupted. I changed to a different monitor and it keeps working but receiving garbage from the I2C bus

Comment: @SteveMathwig unfortunately, I have no other option but to use I2C sensors and apply all of my engineering "power" to minimise the corruption of the I2C bus. I am sure that I have yet to explore different techniques to tackle this :)

Comment: @DanielMelendrez How many sensors per heater? What is the measurement time per sensor? Furthermore, my impression of this kind of thermal system is that it's not "fast", what's your heating rate at max power? What's your cooling rate when the heater is off? You may find you do have the time to skip heating pulses and make measurements if your plant bandwidth is lower than expected. Also I2C devices should be able to talk at a minimum of 100kbit/s - that's 100 bits per millisecond, and that strikes me as lots of time to get some messages across.

Comment: I suppose too secret for at least a partial pcb layout, which is what we really need to see here.

Comment: @ErikFriesen sadly, yes. There are a number of NDAs involved. I cannot go any further than this with my description. Just picture a serpentine heater on one side of a multi-layer PCB and a group of I2C temperature sensors on the opposite side. Separate wires to to the heaters voltage and to the I2C bus

Comment: There is really not much to work with. If the heaters can have separate power wiring, why not have two wires for the PWMed heater and 4 wires for I2C bus, with same ground and supply than for MCU? It's not that isolation can provide same separation how currents flow, but as there is no isolation anyway because they all use same battery, so why not just wire the currents similarly how they would flow with isolation. Also you don't share how the scope probe was attached when you measured those spikes. They may not be real and may be an artifact of selecting probe placement poorly.

Comment: It might be the case you have designed yourself a transformer. The i2c signals should not run parallel with the heater tracks. Run them at an angle to minimise coupling. Other thoughts would be to avoid using pwm on the heater. Instead use a buck converter for a controllable current source. Putting a ground plane won’t help with magnetic coupling if this is the case. You can isolate all you like and it won’t make a scrap of difference. At a pinch I’d try snubbers across the heaters and lower the I2C pullup resistor values.

Comment: @Bryan you touched on extremely good points. I believe that amongst the very few options that I have, adequate timings and careful algorithmic design are crucial. Based on these comments I will start working right away on capturing temperatures while keeping the PWM pulses off. Thanks again

Comment: @Justme the wiring you describe is precisely the way everything is wired up at the moment. The I2C signals were acquired directly from the SDA and SCL lines using the shortest GND connections possible. The probes were securely attached to their respective test points. The corruption is real, you can count on that

Comment: @Kartman I completely agree with you and I have already described this to my "customer". We should not be mixing the signals involved in such a _weird_ configuration. I think you gave me a  great piece of advice for me here. Using a buck converter _might_ yield different results. I will definitely test that! Agree on the isolation. I think ground planes won't do much against coupling. I will play around with the pull-ups too! By the way, all heaters have snubbers too, however, thy might need some improvements. Thanks!